# What are the values in the white balance menu in D40 refer to?

Tags: white-balance, nikon-d40

In D40 whitebalance menu,I found values like +3, +2, +1, 0, -1, -2, -3 in each setting. Does that represent values related to Kelvins?

Comment: I haven't found a reference for what it is exactly, but it's certainly not +-3 degrees kelvin, that would not be a noticable difference. It might be that each step represents 100 degrees, or perhaps more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a warmth adjustment that lets you "fine tune" the white balance for aesthetics (as opposed to accuracy). You might find that a value of "+1" (a little warmer, approximately the same as an 81A filter) gives more pleasing (or healthier-looking) skin tones than the flat "0" setting does, or that a +2 or +3 makes autumn foliage look better. You may find that winter landscapes look a little more "wintery" with a setting of -1 or -2 (cooler than the "accurate" value). It's most useful for JPEGs, of course; with NEFs you can alwayss fine-tune without penalty in post-processing.

Answer (score 1):

**They are relative numbers intended to shift color temperature by perceptually uniform steps.**

There is an underlying unit called the [Mired](http://thedaileyinfo.com/mired-scale/) and each step corresponds to an undisclosed number of them. This is in contrast with fixed steps in the Kelvin scale which would *not* be perceptually uniform.

Comment: Great answer! But, I want to know... Would the 0 be fixed? Or "Auto"? (if you get that I mean)

Comment: 0 is relative to the chosen WB. Each Preset, for example, *Cloudy* corresponds to a certain color-temperature in Kelvin. An adjustment of 0 means that there is no offset. It works similarly to EC where WB Fine-Tuning is adjustment over the set (Preset) or *metered* (Auto) value. When you set a Kelvin temperature explicitly, many camera disable adjustments.